# One or more errors occurred on ReadAsAsync. Exception sometimes thrown, sometimes not

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I get this error:

```
One or more errors occurred.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at MyClass.<GetTranslations>d__1d.MoveNext() in 
...\MyClass.cs:line 719
```

And here's what I have on that line in my code:

```
var myTranslations = 
              response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<MyTranslationModel>>().Result;
```

The code sometimes works (depending on the data), and sometimes it crashes. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you not `await`ing the task?

Comment: @DanielMann How do you mean? I'm not using the await keyword in my application.

Comment: You should be. That's my point.

Comment: @DanielMann I can't because I don't want my methods to be asynchronous.

Comment: You are receiving an AggregateException, check the inner exceptions property of that to see what actually went wrong

Comment: @DanielMann You can't mix asynchronous and ....whatever non asynchronous is...normal(synchronous)?

Comment: @CalvinSmith If it's not asynchronous then it's synchronous.

Comment: @petko_stankoski If you don't want the method to be asynchronous then why are you using an asynchronous method here at all?  Just use a synchronous method.

Answer (score -1):

If your using threads and async, use the await keyword to make sure you don't call the next method before its ready.

The problem isn't specifically this line, it is a result of whatever methods this line calls, which looks like MoveNext()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/async

Comment: `Result` will synchronously block until the `Task` completes.

Comment: You're claiming that execution is continuing without the task being completed.  That won't happen.

Comment: Now I guess I'm confused. It looks like he is starting a new thread(Thread B), launching it asynchrously, then main thread is trying to read the results without thread(b) without thread(b) being completed

Comment: He's not using multiple threads at all.  He's using an asynchronous IO operation and then synchronously waiting on it.